# Filter Object List & Bind to Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an object (please see code below) which contains a list. This list is currently binded to a datagrid in my WPF application.

What I would like to do is to have two datagrids bounded to my object List. I want the top grid to show all the items that have a Status of true. The bottom datagrid would show all the items that have a Status of false. I want both datagrids to be bound to the same object List. Can someone please send me some example code of how to do this?

C# Code

```
class OrderBlocks
{
   public string setting;
   public List<Order> Orders;
}

class Order
{
  public double Amount;
  public int Name;
  public bool Status;
}
```

XAML Code

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}"
                  Name="dataGridOrders" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"/>
```

Comment: `Can someone please send me some example code of how to do this?` - **No**. *"Gimme the codez"* type of requests are not welcome in StackOverflow. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could create 2 properties in your OrderBlocks class

```
    public List<Order> OrdersWithStatusTrue 
    { 
      get { return Orders.Where(x => x.Status); }
    }

    public List<Order> OrdersWithStatusFalse
    {
      get { return Orders.Where(x => !x.Status); }
    }
```

and bind the first grid to the first property the second one to other.

Comment: Hi Syned - thanks for the reply. It does work apart from one thing. When one of the status's is changed from true to false I was hoping the item would be moved from one datagrid to the other, but nothing happens?

Comment: After you changed the status you should notify wpf system about that by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged